# Value of xml node returning as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an xml document that I am loading in my asp .net application. It is structured like this

```
-<Event>

    <Event_Name>Special Name</Event_Name>
    <Event_Date>5/27/2016 12:00:00 AM</Event_Date>
    <Event_Description>Event Description</Event_Description>

</Event>
```

I am loading it in my code behind like this

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/NewsXMLNews.xml");
    doc.Load(path);
```

This loads properly. The problem is, I want to set the Event_Name as the text of a label on my aspx page. I do this using the following code

```
   string nameOfEvent = doc.SelectSingleNode("Event_Name").ToString();
   eventName.Text = nameOfEvent;
```

The problem is that nameOfEvent is coming back as null, so I get a `nullReferenceException`

I'm not exactly what I'm doing incorrectly here.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


-<Event>

<Event_Name>Special Name</Event_Name>

<Event_Date>5/27/2016 12:00:00 AM</Event_Date>

<Event_Description>Event Description</Event_Description>

</Event>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
XmlNode nameOfEvent = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Event/Event_Name");
string text = nameOfEvent.InnerText;
eventName.Text = text;
```

Comment: This was it. So innerText is what I needed. Thank you Mike!

Answer (score 1):

Since you already checked the path is correct and the document is properly loaded I think you just need to change the following line:

```
    string nameOfEvent = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Event/Event_Name").InnerText;
```

Edit: I check with following steps that xml loading process works:

1. I remove the minus before  in described xml file and saved
   following lines as c:\temp\Event.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <Event> 
      <Event_Name>Special Name</Event_Name> 
      <Event_Date>5/27/2016 12:00:00 AM</Event_Date> 
      <Event_Description>Event Description</Event_Description> 
   </Event>
   ```
2. Then I succeeded in running:

   ```
      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();            
          XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
          string path = "c:\\temp\\Event.xml"; 
          doc.Load(path); 
          string nameOfEvent = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Event/Event_Name").InnerText; 
          eventName.Text = nameOfEvent;
      }
   ```
3. In my window I see Label named `eventName` text is *Special Name*
   as expected.

Comment: I thought this would work. It just sets 'System.Xml.XmlElement' as the text of the label

Comment: @TommasoCerutti - Please don't put lots of code in a comment.  Instead, edit your answer and add the code there.  If the code is already in your answer, then consider deleting your comment.

Comment: The only information in comment is "remove the minus before <Event> in your xml file",
 @ChrisDunaway thank you, I'm deleting comment right now, it was my first one and I din't know code can't be formatted